Old film about a guy who becomes rich and successful but never forget his sled
I saw this black and white movie a long time ago, but it's obviously even older since it was black and white.
It's the story of a boy who is taken from his parents when he is young, and his prize possession, a wooden sled, is taken from him and thrown in the fire. He goes on to become a multi millionaire, own loads of industries and live alone in a huge palace called Shangri-la. However he never gets over the loss of his sled. On his deathbed he asks to have it back.
Can't remember many more details, except that at some point his girlfriend gets libelled by a newspaper, and he buys the newspaper company up, just to shut it down. I think it's from the latter days of black and white, but it could be from closer to the start of talkies.
I would be so grateful if someone can guess the name of it so I have a chance of watching it again.

The most famous movie of all time
Citizen Kane (1941) with Orson Welles.

In a mansion in Xanadu, a vast palatial estate in Florida, the elderly Charles Foster Kane is on his deathbed. Holding a snow globe, he utters a word, "Rosebud", and dies; the globe slips from his hand and smashes on the floor. A newsreel obituary tells the life story of Kane, an enormously wealthy newspaper publisher. Kane's death becomes sensational news around the world, and the newsreel's producer tasks reporter Jerry Thompson with discovering the meaning of "Rosebud".
[...]
Back at Xanadu, Kane's belongings are being cataloged or discarded. Thompson concludes that he is unable to solve the mystery and that the meaning of Kane's last word will forever remain an enigma. As the film ends, the camera reveals that "Rosebud" is the trade name of the sled on which the eight-year-old Kane was playing on the day that he was taken from his home in Colorado. Thought to be junk by Xanadu's staff, the sled is burned in a furnace.
Wikipedia


*most famous in the U.S. (and reasonably well known in English-speaking countries).

Also worth noting that the part about the sled is the most famous spoiler in cinematic history (perhaps second only to Luke Skywalker's parentage).

It's been topping the list of Greatest Films of All Time for 50 years..until about 4 years ago...

Technically, "greatest" <> "most famous". While I doubt anyone would consider him the greatest leader of Germany, I don't think there's any question who its most famous leader was. (By not actually bringing up the name, perhaps I manage not to invoke Godwin's Law?)
